# Всегда выдает нули в ответе. C Visual studio 2019

Tags: c, типы-данных, ввод, visual-studio-2019

Первое задание в вузе было вычислить площадь треугольника по высоте и синусам трех углов. Делал по образцу, препод сказал, что не знает чем помочь, ибо ошибки в коде не видит. В ответе всегда выдает 0,000000.

```
void main()

{ 

int A, B, C, h, S;

setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");

printf("Введите высоту h\n");
scanf_s("%f", &h);

printf("Введите первый угол A\n");
scanf_s("%lf", &A);

printf("Введите второй угол B\n");
scanf_s("%lf", &B);

printf("Введите третий угол C\n");
scanf_s("%lf", &C);

S = (h * h * sin(A)) / (2 * sin(B) * sin(C));

printf("%lf", &S);

getchar(),
    getchar();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Гнать такого препода в три шеи...

```
scanf_s("%f", &h);
scanf_s("%lf", &A);
```

и так далее — вы читаете `float` и `double` в переменную типа `int`! Понятно, что получается ерунда.

Результат преобразуете в `int` — теряете дробную часть.

Да и выводите по сути адрес, приведенный в `double`.

```
printf("%lf", &S);
```

Потом,

```
void main()
```

Я вообще не понимаю, как вы это скомпилировали.

И, надеюсь, вы знаете, как правильно вводить числа с плавающей точкой в русской локали...